# "-puzzle" tags not allowed

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

When I try to save a questions tagged with <kbd>calculation-puzzle</kbd>, <kbd>logic-puzzle</kbd>, <kbd>mechanical-puzzle</kbd>, <kbd>twisty-puzzle**s**</kbd>, or whatever tag containing "-puzzle", I get the error message *"The 'puzzle' tag is not allowed"*.

If this behaviour is intended, could we burninate those tags and provide useful alternatives? If not, did somebody mess up with a regular expression and can we have the problem solved? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intent was to forbid [tag:puzzle] (and [tag:puzzles]) only. *That* tag conveys no information whatsoever. Tags with the name of the site are normally forbidden for this reason; here “puzzle” is a variation of “puzzling”. We can take this as an opportunity to decide whether we want to standardize tag names on XXX, XXX-puzzle or XXX-puzzles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just took a look at our tag blacklist, and it has this:

```
^puzzling|puzzles?$
```

Turns out that really means `(^puzzling)|(puzzles?$)`, which blacklists any tag that starts with "puzzling" or ends with "puzzle" or "puzzles." Definitely not the intent.

I've poked an employee in chat to fix this for us.

Comment: It is fixed now.